# do-while and while comparison

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

do-while:

```
do
{ 
    i++; 
    ++j;
    System.out.println( i * j );

}
while ((i < 10) && (j*j != 25));
```

I am learning about do-while vs while at the moment and would like to rewrite the above java fragment (already declared and initialized) using a while instead. Are the below rewritten codes correct way to do so:

while:

```
while ((i < 10) && (j*j != 25))
{
    i++;  
    ++j;
    System.out.println( i * j );
}
```

Comment: The difference is *when* the condition check occurs, of course. In a do-while, the body is always executed *at least once*. Otherwise, there really is nothing to say.

Comment: `while` is an *entry check loop*, whereas `do-while` is an *exit-check loop*. And **NO**, what you mentioned is not the right way to interchange the loop, while having the functionality intact.

Comment: dont compare by execution , compare by definition first , then you'll know where to expect the change

Comment: Thank you for explaining this so quickly guys, much appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference between a `do-while` and a `while` is **when** the comparison is done. With a `do-while`, you'll compare at the end and hence do at least one iteration.

#### Equivalent code for your example

```
do
{ 
    i++; 
    ++j;
    System.out.println( i * j );

}
while ((i < 10) && (j*j != 25));
```

is equivalent to:

```
i++; 
++j;
System.out.println( i * j );
while ((i < 10) && (j*j != 25)) {
    i++; 
    ++j;
    System.out.println( i * j );
}
```

#### General comprehension

A `do-while` loop is an *exit controlled loop* which means that it exits at the end. A `while` loop is an *entry controlled loop* which means that the condition is tested at the beginning and as a consequence, the code inside the loop might not even be executed.

```
do {
    <block>
} while (<condition>);
```

is equivalent to:

```
<block>
while (<condition>) {
    <block>
};
```

#### Use case

A typical use case for a `do-while` is the following: you ask the user something and you want do repeat the operation while the input is not correct.

```
do {
   // Ask something
} while (input is not correct);
```

In that case, you want to ask at least once and it's usually more elegant than using a `while` which would require either to duplicate code, or to add an extra condition or setting an arbitrary value to force entering the loop the first time.

At the opposite, `while` loops are much more commons and can easily replace a `do-while` (not all languages have both loops).

Comment: Whilst it shows for this example how it is done, it misses the point that the logic needs to be rethought.

Comment: @user2860598 I tried to take into consideration your comment. Is it better? Do you think something else should be explained?

Comment: @user2860598 I suppose what I was trying to get it, is how do you change from to the other...which the only way to explain is very examples. Good post :D

Comment: I know this is old but, why do you need to repeat the whole block outside the while? Why not just have the declaration and initialization of the variables? Like `int i = 0, j = 0; while ((i < 10) && (j*j != 25)) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

**The key difference between `do-while` and `while`, with `do-while` you are guaranteed at least one run of your code before the checks.**

**It does not need to get anymore complicated than that.*

Answer (score 2):

No, the two codes are not equivalent. `do-while` only checks the condition at the end of the loop so `i++`, `++j` and `System.out.println(i * j)` happen at least once regardless of the initial values of `i` and `j`. `while` skips the entire loop if the condition isn't `true` for the first time the loop is entered.

You can achieve the same effect with `while` by copying the loop's body once before the loop, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Do-While loops are pretty useful for cases like these, where you ask the user a question, and the user has to answer it for the program to terminate.
For example, this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoWhile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int answer;
        do {
            System.out.println("What is 5+5?");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            answer = scan.nextInt();
        } while (answer != 10);
    }
}
```