# How to test method which uses Random() but can't pick the same number twice

Tags: java, testing, random, mockito

I'm creating a little java game which randomly picks from a list of Primitive data (using `Random().nextInt()`) types and asks which type is larger (or if they're both the same). I've also made it so that if the same Primitive data type is picked then `random.nextInt()` is called again to ensure the selections are different.

My trouble now comes in testing that the code works. Below is the Game.class:

```
static final PrimitiveDataType BOOLEAN_TYPE = new PrimitiveDataType("boolean", 0);
    static final PrimitiveDataType BYTE_TYPE = new PrimitiveDataType("byte", 8);
    static final PrimitiveDataType SHORT_TYPE = new PrimitiveDataType("short", 16);
    static final PrimitiveDataType CHAR_TYPE = new PrimitiveDataType("char", 16);
    static final PrimitiveDataType INT_TYPE = new PrimitiveDataType("int", 32);
    static final PrimitiveDataType LONG_TYPE = new PrimitiveDataType("long", 64);
    static final PrimitiveDataType FLOAT_TYPE = new PrimitiveDataType("float", 32);
    static final PrimitiveDataType DOUBLE_TYPE = new PrimitiveDataType("double", 64);
static List<PrimitiveDataType> PRIMITIVE_TYPES = Arrays.asList(BOOLEAN_TYPE, BYTE_TYPE, SHORT_TYPE, CHAR_TYPE,
        INT_TYPE, LONG_TYPE, FLOAT_TYPE, DOUBLE_TYPE);

static List<PrimitiveDataType> chosenDataTypes = new ArrayList<PrimitiveDataType>();

private static int numberOfQuestions; 

static Random numberGenerator = new Random();

static void setChosenDataTypeIndexs(Random numberGenerator) {




    int choice1 =  numberGenerator.nextInt(PRIMITIVE_TYPES.size()-1)+0;
    int choice2 =  numberGenerator.nextInt(PRIMITIVE_TYPES.size()-1)+0;

    System.out.println("Random Roll (1) " +choice1);
    System.out.println("Random Roll (2) " +choice2);
    do {

        choice2 = numberGenerator.nextInt(PRIMITIVE_TYPES.size()-1)+0;

    } while (choice1==choice2);

    Game.chosenDataTypes.add(PRIMITIVE_TYPES.get(choice1));
    Game.chosenDataTypes.add(PRIMITIVE_TYPES.get(choice2));

}

static PrimitiveDataType getChosenDataTypeIndexs(int i) {
    return chosenDataTypes.get(i);
}

public static void setNumberOfQuestions(int i) {

    numberOfQuestions = i;

}
```

I've had a go with writing a testclass with Mockito, but i'm not sure if i'm mocking correctly due to getting passing test with the dice roll outputting the same number. Also, if i mock out the output of Random.nextInt() to a specific wouldn't this create an infinite loop as it looks for a different number?

```
public class GameTest {





@Test
public void getChosenDataTypesTest(){


    Random randomNumberMock = Mockito .mock(Random.class);
    when(randomNumberMock.nextInt()).thenReturn(1);

    Game.setChosenDataTypeIndexs(randomNumberMock);

    assertNotEquals(Game.chosenDataTypes.get(0), Game.chosenDataTypes.get(1));

    verify(randomNumberMock,times(2)).nextInt();




}
@Test
public void setNumberOfQuestionsTest(){




    Game.setNumberOfQuestions(1);

    assertEquals(1,Game.getNumberOfQuestions());


}
```

EDIT: After much searching I've been advised to inject a Picker interface into the GameRunner which can be swapped out for test Picker which outputs fixed picks. I've also created a Picks Class to be responsible for picking the Primitive data types. this has worked well and eliminated the need for using a mocking framework entirely.

The `fixedPrimitivePicker` uses a stack of set `PrimitiveDataTypes` that pop's off `PrimitiveDataType` Objects each time it

```
package org.FaneFonseka.LearningGames2;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Stack;


/**
 * Created by Fane on 23/12/2016.
 */
public class PicksTest {


private Picks picks;
private Picker fixedPrimitivePicker;
private Stack<PrimitiveDataType> primitiveDataTypeStack;
private PrimitiveDataType primitive1;
private PrimitiveDataType primitive2;
private PrimitiveDataType primitive3;

@Before
public void setup() {


    primitiveDataTypeStack = new Stack<PrimitiveDataType>();
    primitiveDataTypeStack.push(primitive3 = new PrimitiveDataType("int", 32));
    primitiveDataTypeStack.push(primitive2 = new PrimitiveDataType("boolean", 1));
    primitiveDataTypeStack.push(primitive1 = new PrimitiveDataType("boolean", 1));

    fixedPrimitivePicker = new Picker() {

        public PrimitiveDataType pick() {

            return primitiveDataTypeStack.pop();

        }
    };
    picks = new Picks(fixedPrimitivePicker);

}

@Test
public void setFirstPickTest() {

    picks.setPicks();

    assert picks.getFirstPick().equals(primitive1);


}

@Test
public void setSecondPickTest() {

    picks.setPicks();
    assert picks.getSecondPick().equals(primitive3);
}

@Test
public void secondPickIsDifferentFromFirstPickTest() {

    picks.setPicks();
    assert !picks.getFirstPick().equals(picks.getSecondPick());

}



}
```

and the Picks Class:

```
package org.FaneFonseka.LearningGames2;

class Picks {
private PrimitiveDataType firstPick;
private PrimitiveDataType secondPick;
private Picker randomPrimitivePicker;

Picks(Picker randomPrimitivePicker) {
    this.randomPrimitivePicker = randomPrimitivePicker;
}

boolean firstPickGreaterThanSecondPick() {

    System.out.println(getFirstPick().getMemorySizeInBits() > getSecondPick().getMemorySizeInBits());
    return getFirstPick().getMemorySizeInBits() > getSecondPick().getMemorySizeInBits();
}

boolean secondPickGreaterThanFirstPick() {

    System.out.println(getFirstPick().getMemorySizeInBits() < getSecondPick().getMemorySizeInBits());
    return getFirstPick().getMemorySizeInBits() < getSecondPick().getMemorySizeInBits();
}

boolean firstPickIsSameSizeAsSecondPick() {
    System.out.println(getFirstPick().getMemorySizeInBits() == getSecondPick().getMemorySizeInBits());
    return getFirstPick().getMemorySizeInBits() == getSecondPick().getMemorySizeInBits();
}

void setPicks() {
    setFirstPick(randomPrimitivePicker);
    setSecondPick(randomPrimitivePicker);

}

private void setFirstPick(Picker randomPrimitivePicker) {

    this.firstPick = randomPrimitivePicker.pick();
}

PrimitiveDataType getFirstPick() {

    return this.firstPick;
}

private void setSecondPick(Picker randomPrimitivePicker) {

    PrimitiveDataType pick;

    do {
        pick = randomPrimitivePicker.pick();
    } while (pick.equals(firstPick));

    this.secondPick = pick;

}

PrimitiveDataType getSecondPick() {

    return secondPick;
}


}
```

If you want to see the rest of the project it can be found here:

https://github.com/fane247/LearningGames2

Answer (score 6):

You can add variety to your test with [Chained stubbing](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.22/org/mockito/Mockito.html#10), so that you are not testing with random returning always same number.

```
 when(randomNumberMock.nextInt())
   .thenReturn(4)
   .thenReturn(12);
```

You could also parameterize your test. Here is example for [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders).

```
@DataProvider()
public static Object[][] randomNumbers() {
    return new Object[][] {{2, 3}, {6, 7}, {19, 15}};
}

@Test(dataProvider = "random")
public void getChosenDataTypesTest(int first, int second) {
 when(randomNumberMock.nextInt())
   .thenReturn(first)
   .thenReturn(second);
}
```

JUnit has similar feature for [parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests).

EDIT:
Mocked method has to be

> nextInt(anyInt())

because you are calling nextInt(int bound) not nextInt().

```
when(randomNumberMock.nextInt(anyInt())
   .thenReturn(4)
   .thenReturn(12);
```

Comment: When i use the when(randomNumberMock.nextInt())
   .thenReturn(4)
   .thenReturn(12); method the test goes into an infinite loop where both dice rolls are 0?

Comment: See the edit. We were mocking wrong method. Mocked method was nextInt() but code called nextInt(int bound) which was returning 0.

Comment: Also your verify check will fail, because you are always calling anyInt at least three times. do-while does the condition check after first loop.

Comment: Good spot this is now calling the correct numbers. However, I want to check the logic within setChosenDataTypeIndexs(). Namely, if the same number is chosen by the random number generator it calls until the number is different. Do you know how I can go about this?

Comment: Just use "while (choice1==choice2) { ... }" This way it will check first and generate new value only if they are the same.

Comment: not sure if this is a null point but I already have this bit of code in the Game.class file. Do I need to create test to create a scenario when two numbers that are the same are chosen as choices to test this or is it not necessary?

Comment: What I meant is that you can get rid of redundant random call in Game class. Check the difference between the while loop and the do-while loop. See links below. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044845/do-while-and-while-comparison