# want to change ASCII while to do~while and for

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ASCII {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s;
        char c;

        while(true){
            System.out.println("insert letters. (insert # exit)");
            s = scan.next();
            c = s.charAt(0);
            if(c == '#')
                break;
            System.out.print(c + " ASCII code " + (int)c + "end");
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

i want to change while to do~while
           and    while to for.
 i tried it but i don't know how to change the if part.

Comment: Do you want to change it to do-while or while-to? Have you Googled how to use either in Java?

Comment: The pattern you are using seems appropriate to me.  Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/20044890/9206488

Comment: i'm learning to change it but the if parts making me so sad

Comment: Please also show us how you tried to change your code

Answer (score 0):

your question isn't exactly clear, but maybe this is what you had in mind :

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s;
        char c;
        do {
            System.out.println("insert letters. (insert # exit)");
            s = scan.next();
            c = s.charAt(0);
            System.out.print(c + " ASCII code " + (int)c + " end \n");
        } while(c != '#');
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do- while loop is there in Java:

```
do{
            System.out.println("insert letters. (insert # exit)");
            s = scan.next();
            c = s.charAt(0);
            if(c == '#')
                break;
            System.out.print(c + " ASCII code " + (int)c + "end");
        }while(true);
```